# Filter odd numbers without using filter function in Clojure

Tags: filter, clojure

how can I filter odd numbers and put them into a vector? (For educational purposes I know a better way to use the filter function)

My attempt is:

```
(map
  (fn [x] (if (odd? x) (into [] cat x)))
  (range 0 10))
```

Expected output:

```
;=> [1 3  5 7 9]
```

Second question: In (if) function how can I set the when if condition is false then do exactly nothing. When if I leave it empty It brings nil. I don't want that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: also `(for [x (range 10) :when (odd? x)] x)`

Comment: @FrankHenard, the op was asking about a way to do this without using `filter` function )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn filter-odd
  [vals]
  (reduce
    (fn [cum item]
      ; Decide how to modify `cum` given the current item
      (if (odd? item)
        (conj cum item) ; if odd, append to cum result
        cum ; if even, leave cum result unchanged
        ))
    []    ; init value for `cum`
    vals ; sequence to reduce over
  ))

(verify
  (is= (filter-odd (range 10))
    [1 3 5 7 9]))
```

You could also use `loop/recur` to mimic the functionality of the `reduce` function.

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Answer (score 1):

Here is `loop` version:

```
(loop [numbers (range 10)
       result  []]
    (let [x (first numbers)]
      (cond
        (empty? numbers) result
        (and (int? x) (odd? x)) (recur (rest numbers) (conj result x))
        :else (recur (rest numbers) result))))
```

Comment: thanks and sorry about my late reply :)